# PTIJ: Who is Robert?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We often name our children after those who were important personages in the Torah and post Torah period, those who had a major impact on our identity as Jews.

But who was "Robert" that so many of the sages in the Talmud were named after him? There was Robby Yishma'el, Robby Yehuda and Robby Yosi to name a few. Was Robert an important role model who passed away young, thus explaining the use of the diminutive?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

It is well known that "Robert" and "Bob" are the same name. Thus, when [Mishnah Bava Kamma 9:3](http://mishna.alhatorah.org/Full/Bava_Kamma/9.3#e0n6) refers to "Habanai", or "The Builder", we see clearly that they were aware of [this great person](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%95%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99), whom they surely named their children after.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to say that there is no great Robert that the sages were named after. The names you're used to hearing, such as Robby Yishma'el, Robby Yehudah, and Robby Yosi are all misnomers caused by corruptions in Ashkenazic voweling of Talmudic texts. There is no רָבִי (Robby) in the Talmudic text, the honorific should be pronounced as רִבִי (Ribbi) which is how it's written in Sephardic and Yemenite manuscripts.

So then the real question is who were Ribbi Yishma'el, Ribbi Yehudah, and Ribbi Yosi named after? In truth they are all paying homage to the great wisdom imparted onto our sages by frogs, who often chant Ribbi/Ribbit as they contemplate the mysteries of the holy Torah.

Here are just two such stories of the holyness of frogs, for which we owe so much Torah.

> God says to the prophets, 'Think not that if you do not carry my messages, my will cannot be made known in the world. I have many messengers-even such as a scorpion, a snake, a frog, or an insect.'--Mid. Eccles. 5.

Source: https://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/tmm/tmm14.htm

> Rabbi Hanina learned from his deathbed-ridden father that he would
>   lose both his parents on the same day. Further, his father instructed
>   him to go to the market immediately after the mourning period ended
>   (which would be Passover eve) and purchase the first item that he saw.
>   When Hanina went to the market after completing the days of mourning
>   for his parents, he was offered a grossly overpriced silver dish. In
>   the interest of honoring his father, he bought the dish, and upon
>   opening it at the Seder, he found another dish inside holding a frog.
>
> Like a good pet owner Hanina fed the frog, which grew to an enormous
>   size. First he had to build a cabinet to house it, and when it got
>   even larger, an entire room. The frog literally ate Hanina out of
>   house and home, but it recognized the imposition it was presenting and
>   offered Hanina whatever he wished. Hanina asked to be taught the
>   entire Torah, and the frog agreed. It wrote the Torah on paper, which
>   Hanina consumed.
>
> In so doing, he not only learned the whole Torah, but also all 70
>   languages as well as the languages of animals (much like King Solomon
>   did). And just as Solomon, in asking only for knowledge, he also
>   acquired wealth and power. The frog gave Hanina and his wife precious
>   stones and herbs (which carried medicinal powers) and revealed his
>   true identity as one of Adam’s sons, born during his 130-year
>   separation from Eve, who was capable of shape shifting.

Sources: https://www.jewishpress.com/sections/the-frog-the-demons-and-the-jewish-star/2008/10/01/

https://books.google.com/books?id=jM6bDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT73&lpg=PT73&dq=The+Frog+who+taught+Rabbi+Hanina+the+whole+Torah&source=bl&ots=pnqcTbRann&sig=ACfU3U1XPU6FmEjv4VFqO3394enyn4CX6g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDlImptOvnAhVQRa0KHb0rBvIQ6AEwBHoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20Frog%20who%20taught%20Rabbi%20Hanina%20the%20whole%20Torah&f=false

Comment: It's not from corruptions in Ashkenazic voweling of Talmudic texts. It was a 18th century controversial Enlightenment-grammarian who actively changed it in his Ashkenazi Siddur.

Answer (score 1):

Frequently in the Talmud, we see some rabbi who says something and the Talmud points out that another rabbi had said the same thing at a much earlier time and, usually, in a different tractate. Not only is that plagiarism, but it's outright robbery.

So, the Talmud thought of calling these people "robber" as in "Robber Yehuda and Robber Yishma'el". But, the political powers of the time were concerned that future readers would assume that just about everyone in the Talmud was a robber, including the numerous honest people. So, they hid that fact and just called them "robbie".

---

While your question asks about people, I should point out that there are three notable "Bobbies" in the Talmud that have their own tractates named after them:

Bobby Kamma, Bobby Metzia (he was lost for many years, but he found himself, finally), and Bobby Batra.

Answer (score 0):

We find this in several instances. For example, the modern Thaddeus is derived from [Tadi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaddeus) (e.g. רב תדאי, see Shabbos 38b).

Thus, the modern Robert is rooted in the Mishnaic Robby (רבי). It is just a mere coincidence the the way the diminutives function in English have caused the the derived word to match that of its origin.

Answer (score -2):

Rebby Yehuda HaNosi who authored the Mishnayos was known as Rebby.  All the future generations named after him as it would be an honor to be like him. (Source: Toras Purim 4:26)